# Extract String Value using jquery

Tags: jquery

How do I get the value of the text from this input:

I am trying to get the value "Hello" for the text elemen in this input

```
<input id="myText" type="hidden" value="{"enabled":true,"value":"377352:0","text":"Hello","selected":false,"active":true}"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the value looks like a JSON string, use `parseJSON` method to parse it and the access the required property.

```
var value = $.parseJSON($('#myText').val()).text;
```

Refernce: [$.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Note: In your markup the `value` of the input should either enclose its content in single quote or you should escape the double quotes inside the string.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/Ms5wL/)**

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery you could just ask for the element value then it is currently an object so can access via that. Something like the code below should suffice:

```
var value = $('#myText').val();
if (value && typeof(value) === 'object') {
    var text = value.text;
}
```

Text should now hold the value Hello